# getTime() in format 'day-month-year' (Angular)

Tags: angular, date, gettime

In a DB I have a date of birth in format `day-month-year` (like this "`12-07-1997`, `13-07-1997`").
I want to get an age and use function like this:

```
if (birthday) {
  let timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - new Date(birthday).getTime());
  let age = Math.floor(timeDiff / (24 * 3600 * 1000) / 365.25);
  console.log(age + ' y.o.')
}
```

In first example it returns `22 y.o.`, but in case of `13-07-1997` I have `NaN y.o.`.
I think its 'cause of format of the date. Any ideas how should I correctly use `getTime()` here?

Would be really grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date('13-07-1997')` is getting `Invalid Date` , this the reason why you are getting `NaN`, Please try below code

```js
  let birthdayString="13-07-1997";
  let dateParts = birthdayString.split("-");
  let newB=new Date(+dateParts[2], parseInt(dateParts[1]) - 1, +dateParts[0]);
  var ageDifMs = Date.now() - newB.getTime();
  var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
  console.log("your age is" ,Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  let birthdayString="13-07-1997";
  let dateParts = birthdayString.split("-");
  let newB=new Date(+dateParts[2], parseInt(dateParts[1]) - 1, +dateParts[0]);
  var ageDifMs = Date.now() - newB.getTime();
  var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
  console.log("your age is" ,Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970));
```